# RewriteRule in .htacces to match my GET parameter needs

Tags: php, .htaccess

In our project, we started using .htaccess to prettify urls. Everything worked nice, untill I found, that our facebook login doesnt want to work, because GET parameters, that fb returns, cannot be catched in our code.

```
RewriteRule ^social/facebook$ /index.php/?action=social&authsocial=facebook
```

This rule breaks everything I need.
it changes `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/?action=social&authsocial=facebook` to `http://www.mydomain.com/social/facebook`.

So it parses 2 GET parameters. But when I use facebook login, they return bunch of GET parameters. How could I make rule, that would result in something like this
`http://www.mydomain.com/social/facebook?param1=12&qqq=13` ?

Basicly keep first part as it is now, but add not constant GET parameters as in old style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append query string. You can achieve it by adding `[QSA]` at the end of `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^social/facebook$ /index.php/?action=social&authsocial=facebook [QSA,L]
```

[From documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.